# Please how do I generate sentences from forms?

Tags: forms, sentence

A user fills a form.  Using the text from the form, the program automatically generate sentences.

For example:

> `[enter name]`, a `[student/professor]` of `[enter name of university]`, received the award of `[enter award]` in his research on `[name of topic]`; the award was given at the `[name of conference]` in `[name of country]`. The conference was attended by eminent scientists from all over the world.

The generated text will become:

> **Muhammad Afiq**, a student of **University of Technology Petronas**, received the award of excellence in his research on **oil pipeline routing**; the award was given at the **Conference on Green Technology** in **Malaysia**.  The conference was attended by eminent scientists from all over the world.

Do you know which technology or language I can use to learn how to do this?
I'm a journalist.  So I'm looking for a way to design a simple program that'll enable me to fill a form when I don't feel like writing.

I know some Python but I've not been able to use it to create this program.  All my searches (including on this site) so far have been returning results in NLP and AI - not what I want.  Maybe I'm using the wrong search terms?

Please could you point me to a place where I can learn how to do this or is there a module somewhere?

Thanks.

Edit:

I tried this using Python:

```
full_name =input("enter name")
occupation =input("enter occupation")
name_of_university =input("enter name of university")
award= input("enter award received")
topic=input("enter topic")
conference =input("enter name of conference")
country =input("enter name of country")
display_concatenation =   full_name+occupation+name_of_university+award+topic+conference+country
print (display_concatenation)
```

It didn't work.

Comment: "It didn't work." is usually the worst error description one could get.

Comment: Uwe Keim, sorry about that.  I'm quite new to this programming lingo.  What I meant was that after the user enters all the information, the program gives a badly formatted result like this: "Ibraheem DoobastudentUTPbest paperoil pipeline routingConference on Green TechnologyMalaysia"

Answer (score 0):

I believe that almost all languages support strings. So let's say the name is in a field "fullName" you would start building the string with

```
string sentence = fullName.Value() + ", a " + ..
```

http://www.w3schools.com/ is a good site you can start with. Java, .NET, Python, Ruby will all do so it's just a personal choice

Comment: "string sentence = fullName.Value() + ", a " + .."  Sir, are you saying the solution is a matter of concatenation?

Comment: Most certainly. If you want to generate this type of sentences. You can create an array of constructions and use a Random function ( which is present in almost all languages ) to create some weird stuff. Sadly I have no experience with Python so I can't help further.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your idea, shouldn't it be like this?

```
name = raw_input("Your name")
student_proff = raw_input("Student/proffessor")
s = "[enter name], a [student/professor] of [enter name of university], received the award of [enter award] in his research on [name of topic]; the award was given at the [name of conference] in [name of country]. The conference was attended by eminent scientists from all over the world."
print s
s = s.replace("[enter name]", name).replace("[student/professor]", student_proff)
print s
```

**UPDATED:** Added working example :)

Comment: Nope.  I couldn't follow your code.  The variables and the code were all mixed-up on my IDLE. Please could you answer the question again - this time explain as if I'm a complete idiot?

Comment: Aleksej, you're a genius!  It worked with the two variables you used as examples.